# Is this the right way to get Data with UTF8 encoding with MySQL and UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode, utf-8

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once 'convertArraytoJson.php';

$connection=mysql_connect ( "localhost", $databaseuser, $databasepassword );
//mysql_set_charset('utf8'); //Is this better than the last line? 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'"); //Which one is better?
@mysql_select_db ($databasename) or die ( "Unable to select database" );
$query="SELECT `Building` FROM `tablebuilding` WHERE ID=51";
$data = mysql_query($query);
while (true){
    $info = mysql_fetch_array ( $data, MYSQL_ASSOC );
    if ($info == false) {
        break;
    }
    $output = $info['Building'];
}
//$output is FX Lifestyle X’nter
$v= htmlspecialchars ($output); //Should I use this?


$result = json_encode($output);
//$result is FX Lifestyle X\u2019nter 
echo ($result);

?>
```

Just want to verify is this the right way?

What's the difference between `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` and `mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'");`

and which one are better.

Comment: How are you receiving the JSON? The receiving end should automatically convert the sequence into the actual character.

Comment: Use `mysql_set_charset()`, because this is the only way how `mysql_real_escape_string()` knows about mysql connection encoding.

Comment: We also call `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');`

Comment: @Chris `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');` does not affect `mysql_real_escape_string()`, So `mysql_set_charset()` is better.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is just a open standard for data interchange. If you send your json encoded string, the client will convert your string whith the correct charset if it supports JSON. 
Try to use the client JavaScript interpreter and check if your client supports JSON:

```
 echo "<script>document.write('$result');</script>";
```

Comment: Good answer. I guess I have to make it clear that I am working on the PhP side. Looks like I figure out how to decode the json thingy. I'll delete that part. But \u2019 are indeed ’ right?

Comment: yes \u2019 is the Unicode character for ' [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

Comment: in that case I am looking for info on whether the PhP is correct. Is that the standard way to grab utf8 data from PhP?